# Apache virtual directory backed by VCS?

Tags: apache, version-control, live

There are many VCS web front-end, which you can view/download the latest commit version in a VCS repo, like Trac (for SVN), CVSWeb, etc.

I want something like `http://my.web/abc.html` be directly retrieved from VCS, instead of return a file for download, it should be displayed in the browser, with no extra header/footer at all.

My repositories are in Subversion and Git.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion [does this quite naturally](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic) using an httpd module.  I'm not sure about git, but I did find [some instructions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt).  Be careful not to expose your repo to commits by anonymous users.